# Timezone issue with format(x) where x is POSIXct

Tags: r, timezone, posix, posixct

I am getting an odd timezone issue.  Namely, an extra labeling of 'PDT' when the value is 'EDT'
This is only happening on a remote CENTOS machine.  It does *not* reproduce on my local machine.

```
> format(x, format="%c", tz="America/New_York", usetz=TRUE)
[1] "Fri 25 Jul 2014 12:44:03 AM PDT EDT"


## Note that the correct would be 
## "Thu 24 Jul 2014 09:44:03 PM PDT" if the time were in PDT
```

I tried a few different options with `'format(x)'` as well as a few different options for `'x'`
Below is an example with session info

(feel free to rephrase the question if you see fit)

#### CODE RAN:

```
x <- structure(1406263443, class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York")


cat(rep("\n", 10))
Sys.time()
format(x, format="%c", tz="America/New_York")
format(x, format="%c", tz="America/New_York", usetz=TRUE)
format(x, format="%c", usetz=TRUE)
format(x, format="%c", usetz=FALSE)
format(x, format="%c")
sessionInfo()
```

#### Output on Remote Machine (CENTOS, on the west coast, USA)

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2014-07-24 22:13:05 PDT"

> format(x, format="%c", tz="America/New_York")
[1] "Fri 25 Jul 2014 12:44:03 AM PDT"
> format(x, format="%c", tz="America/New_York", usetz=TRUE)
[1] "Fri 25 Jul 2014 12:44:03 AM PDT EDT"  <~~~ NOTICE
> format(x, format="%c", usetz=TRUE)
[1] "Fri 25 Jul 2014 12:44:03 AM PDT EDT"
> format(x, format="%c", usetz=FALSE)
[1] "Fri 25 Jul 2014 12:44:03 AM PDT"
> format(x, format="%c")
[1] "Fri 25 Jul 2014 12:44:03 AM PDT"  <~~~ Incorrect time. should be 09:44:03 PM PDT day prior

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] RPostgreSQL_0.4  DBI_0.2-7        XML_3.98-1.1     sendmailR_1.1-2  base64enc_0.1-1  data.table_1.9.2
 [7] sos_1.3-8        brew_1.0-6       Revobase_7.0.0   RevoMods_7.0.0   RevoScaleR_7.0.0 lattice_0.20-24
[13] rpart_4.1-4      colorout_1.0-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 foreach_1.4.1   grid_3.0.2      iterators_1.0.6 plyr_1.8        reshape2_1.2.2  stringr_0.6.2
[8] tools_3.0.2
```

#### Output on Local Machine (Mac OS X, on the east coast, USA)

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2014-07-25 01:13:06 EDT"

> format(x, format="%c", tz="America/New_York")
[1] "Fri Jul 25 00:44:03 2014"
> format(x, format="%c", tz="America/New_York", usetz=TRUE)
[1] "Fri Jul 25 00:44:03 2014 EDT"
> format(x, format="%c", usetz=TRUE)
[1] "Fri Jul 25 00:44:03 2014 EDT"
> format(x, format="%c", usetz=FALSE)
[1] "Fri Jul 25 00:44:03 2014"
> format(x, format="%c")
[1] "Fri Jul 25 00:44:03 2014"

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] Rook_1.0-9       Rfacebook_0.4    rjson_0.2.14     httr_0.2         XML_3.95-0.2    
 [6] rJava_0.9-6      lubridate_1.3.1  forecast_5.4     timeDate_3010.98 zoo_1.7-10      
[11] RPostgreSQL_0.4  DBI_0.2-7        reshape2_1.2.2   XLConnect_0.2-7  combinat_0.0-8  
[16] sendmailR_1.1-2  base64enc_0.1-1  data.table_1.9.2 sos_1.3-8        brew_1.0-6      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.3     fracdiff_1.4-2   grid_3.0.2       lattice_0.20-24 
 [6] nnet_7.3-7       parallel_3.0.2   plyr_1.8         quadprog_1.5-5   Rcpp_0.11.1     
[11] RCurl_1.95-4.1   stringr_0.6.2    tseries_0.10-32
```

#### I also tried other values for x with similar results

```
x <- structure(1406263443, class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"))
x <- structure(1406263443, class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Los_Angeles")
x <- Sys.time()
```

Comment: Different timezone database on CentOS and OS X? Generally, the IANA database is used.

Comment: @Pascal, I would be surprised there, although possible.  Nevertheless, why the _duplicate_ time zones showing up in the output?  eg `'PDT EDT'`

Comment: I don't know. On my own machine (OpenSUSE), I get `[1] "Fri 25 Jul 2014 00:44:03 EDT EDT"` when I use `usetz=TRUE`.

Comment: @Pascal, thanks for testing it out.  Seems like it could be a bug then.

Comment: Here's what I have learned to do when struggling with TZ issues: Read the details in `?timezones` and inspect your systems' 'zonetab' files. Make distinctions between `as.POSIXct.numeric` and `as.POSIXct.character`, and also distinctions between input and output. And if you really think it's a bug, don't report it here, do it on r-devel.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, since I don't really know R all that well.  But it seems strange to pass the timezone in the input if you are going to pass it again when formatting it for output.

Try this:

```
x <- structure(1406263443, class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"))
format(x, format="%c", tz="America/New_York", usetz=TRUE)
```

Note, I didn't pass `tzone` when creating `x`.  Passing `NULL` or `""` or `"UTC"` would probably have the same effect.

That said, I tried your code on several online R environments, and never got the duplicated time zone name.  So this may be a red herring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, still same issue though. Output is `"Fri 25 Jul 2014 12:44:03 AM PDT EDT"`

Comment: Ok, then I'm convinced it's a bug, or an issue with environment configuration or something like that.